# scala for comprehension throwing error for Map

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I have the below code snippet, the regular for loop works fine.
But the for comprehension throws error

```
println("Using for loop")
for( (key, value) <- orec.groupBy(x => x.continent) )
  {
  println(key + value.length )
}

println("Using for comprehension")
for{
  (key, value) <- orec.groupBy(x => x.continent)
  println(key + value.length )
} yield (key,value)
```

The Error message is

```
Error:(84, 5) '<-' expected but '}' found.
    } yield (key,value)
```

I could not understand what is wrong with the code. Please help in fixing the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`println` doesn't work within `for` comprehension just like that. It should be like below.

```
for {
  (key, value) <- orec.groupBy(x => x.continent)
  _ = println(key + value.length )
} yield (key,value)
```

1. A for comprehension should always start with <- in its first statement which creates the context for the remaining expression that are following.
2. All `<-` within for comprehension does `flatMap` expect last one which does `map`.

You should use `_ =` for side effecting tasks which doesn't conform to initial context established by for comprehension.

I recommend this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDaw2yXAa50) . It explains for comprehensions more elegantly.

Answer (score 2):

You can´t have prints like that inside a for comprehension, you can use them like this:

```
for{
  (key, value) <- orec.groupBy(x => x.continent) 
} yield println(key + value.length )
```